# How to force navigation bar to show background in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I have the following (on iOS 16):

```
NavigationStack
{
    Form
    {
        ....
    }
}
.navigationTitle("Hello")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

The navigation bar background only appears when scrolling the `Form` upwards.

How can I make sure that the background is always showing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this to always show the background:

```
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```

and this to style it:

```
.toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar)
```

Comment: Didn't know it was this simple; thanks!

Comment: new in ios16 :) - was a hassle before.